# How to read batch submit job payload in job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

`aws_stepfunctions_tasks.BatchSubmitJob` takes a `payload` parameter - Is it possible to access the values from that payload within the job? The use case is that the original code specified `payload={"count.$": "$.count"}` and `container_overrides=aws_stepfunctions_tasks.BatchContainerOverrides(command=["--count", "Ref::count"])`, which forces the `$.count` output of the previous job to be a string. Since I need to use the count for [another value which must be an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66202138/96588) I would like to avoid forcing the data type onto the previous job. Is this possible?